# Can you build custom controller for K8S using the java client API?

Tags: java, kubernetes

Can you use the K8S [java client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) in order to create a custom controller that can react on Custom Resource Definition requests, similar to the one that you can create with the [go client](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

Check this tutorial with official client: [Building stuff with the Kubernetes API (Part 2) — Using Java](https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-2-using-java-ceb8a5ff7920)

This example does not use official client: [microbean-kubernetes-controller](https://github.com/microbean/microbean-kubernetes-controller)